# How Can I Perform $('.div a') in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like the title says, I am looking for a quick way to write following jQuery code `$('.div a')` in "plain" JavaScript. I know we can do `getElementsByClassName` to find `.div`, but how about finding the link it contains?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('a')[0]`

Comment: @Vega assuming it's the first a he wants ^^

Comment: `$('.div a')` will return all anchor elements within the div class, not just the first one.

Comment: @HowardRenollet I rephrased the question a bit. In my case there is only one `a` tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsers have [a native method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx) for accomplishing this:

```
document.querySelectorAll( ".div a" );
```

You can retrieve only the first match with [`querySelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288169(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I cant belive its that easy. I have been "googling" it for half an hour now :) Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `document.querySelectorAll( ".div a" );` instead, as `document.querySelector( ".div a" );` would only return the first match, and `$('.div a')` selects all anchor descendants of `.div`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternate way without using `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

To select all links,

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: again op wants to select all `a` not just the firsts one